# run part of skript only if files in folder had changes with last pull

Tags: git, shell, diff, pull

I have a build script that is run manually (local) or automatically (Jenkins) after a git pull.
It contains parts that could be skipped if there are no changes, like only update translations if there are updates to translations.

It would be quite easy to determine the difference with a git fetch, but I can't figure out how to do this **after a git pull**. Basically, I would need a working replacement for that:

```
if
git diff-tree branch..branch_before_pull | grep -q translations
then

#do looong running part of script here

fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to retrieve the old `origin/master` (assuming you do this for `master` branch) after a `git pull`. Or better, you could do this using the `reflog`, but I would look for a cleaner way since you need to script it.

So, the idea is to make a snapshot of the current `origin/master` before doing a `git pull`, perhaps tagging the commit pointing to it. `git pull` is just a shortcut for running `git fetch` and then `git merge`, the latter is the one we can intercept using a git hook. The only hook you can enable is the [`pre-merge-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit), called only after the merge is completed but before creating the commit (I did not forget about `ff`, see below). This is a possible script:

```
. git-sh-setup

test $(git rev-parse master) != $(git rev-parse origin/master) && \
    git tag -f last_master $(git merge-base master origin/master)

test -x "$GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-commit" &&
        exec "$GIT_DIR/hooks/pre-commit"
:
```

Where the only addition to the default hook is the second command, that compares the current `master` with the one you have just `fetch`ed. If they are different, the tag `last_master` is created (or forced if already exists) and you can use it inside your script as a replacement for `branch_before_pull`. `git merge-base` finds the common ancestor between 2 commits, in your case `master` and `origin/master` (remember that it is already updated to the last `fetch`). Both for a fast forward and a 3-way merge, the found commit is the old `origin/master`.

There is still one thing to fix: what about fast-forwards? In this mode, no merge commit is created, therefore neither the hook is called. This gets painful: to "force" a merge, you can instruct the `pull` operation to forbid fast-forwards. There is an option for this:

```
git pull --no-ff origin master
```

Next you check if the first child of the new `HEAD` (the merge commit) references the same commit of `last_master`, and if it is the case then you perform a hard reset to the new `origin/master`:

```
test $(git rev-parse master^1) = $(git rev-parse last_master) && git reset --hard HEAD^2
```

You could concatenate it with the `git pull` and create an alias for it, or put it inside the [`post-merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge) hook.

Now, a few considerations:

- The `last_master` tag is going to be updated more than necessary, but it is not a real problem since it stays inside your local repository. If it were to be too annoying for whatever reason, just use `git pull --no-verify` to disable the hook for that command only.
- `--no-ff` is so common that you can make it the default option with

  ```
  git config pull.ff 'false'
  ```

  The obvious side effect is that the pull from every branch will follow this behaviour. At the limit, you may want to declare some new aliases.
- Do I like all of this? No. Is there any less painful solution? There might be, but (90% sure) forget the simple one-line command, unless you take it from the `reflog` or exploring the *.git* folder.